# how to hide direct page links from Pagination Directive angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pagination

I am using this Pagination directive

https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/blob/master/src/directives/pagination/README.md

I want hide direct pages links(1,2,3) only need next and previous how to do that ?
I am using this code

http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview

```
<div ng-controller="OtherController" class="other-controller">
          <small>this is in "OtherController"</small>
          <div class="text-center">
          <dir-pagination-controls boundary-links="true" on-page-change="pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)" template-url="dirPagination.tpl.html"></dir-pagination-controls>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use uib-pager directive which is precisely defined for this purpose.
This directive supports all the attributes of uib-pagination directive.

```
<uib-pager total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" align=false></uib-pager>
```

[see documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a custom template which uses the range values along with "previous" and "next" arrow links, but no page links:

```
<div class="range-label">Displaying {{ range.lower }} - {{ range.upper }} of {{ range.total }}</div>
<a href="" title="Previous page" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == 1 }" ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.current - 1)">&lsaquo;</a>
<a href="" title="Next page"  ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == pagination.last }" ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.current + 1)">&rsaquo;</a>
```

check out the link for more details.
https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination#writing-a-custom-pagination-controls-template

Answer (score 0):

Go to dirPagination.tpl.html and delete this line:

```
<li ng-repeat="pageNumber in pages track by tracker(pageNumber, $index)" ng-class="{ active : pagination.current == pageNumber, disabled : pageNumber == '...' }">
    <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pageNumber)">{{ pageNumber }}</a>
</li>
```

Doing that you will now only see the arrows.